# How to identify rows with all non-null values in Rust Polars?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have a `DataFrame` with `null` values and I want to identify rows within which all values are `non-null`. This can be easily achieved in Python with the following code:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, None, None, 1], "b": [None, 1, None, 1]})

df.select(pl.all_horizontal(pl.all().is_not_null())).to_series()
```

The result is as follows:

```
shape: (4,)
Series: 'a' [bool]
[
        false
        false
        false
        true
]
```

However, I would like to implement this on the Rust side. How am I supposed to do it? To be more specific, given a `Rust` `DataFrame`, I would want to return a 'ChunkedArray' identifying whether there are all `non-null` values.

I tried to search something along the same lines as `Python` on `Rust` documentation, such as `all_horizontal`, `all`, but seems not to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rust-polars](/questions/tagged/rust-polars) does have `all` and `all_horizontal` functions available, but I didn't find much documentation around that. But here is how the equivalent functionality can be implemented in [rust-polars](/questions/tagged/rust-polars).

```
use polars::{
    lazy::dsl::{all, all_horizontal},
    prelude::*,
};

fn main() {
    let s1 = Series::new("a", &[Some(1), None, None, Some(1)]);
    let s2 = Series::new("b", &[None, Some(1), None, Some(1)]);
    let df: PolarsResult<DataFrame> = DataFrame::new(vec![s1, s2]);
    
    let new_df = df
        .unwrap()
        .lazy()
        .with_columns(&[all_horizontal(&[all().is_not_null()])
            .unwrap()
            .alias("new_col")])
        .collect()
        .unwrap();

    let new_chunked_bool_array = new_df.column("new_col").unwrap().bool().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", new_array);
}
```

This will print

```
shape: (4,)
ChunkedArray: 'new_col' [bool]
[
        false
        false
        false
        true
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you help show how to make the output a Series or just a ChunkedArray?